# Solving $\ln$ divided by $\ln$.

Tags: logarithms

I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate this. Thank you for your help.

$$0.926 = \frac{\ln(1+0.8u)}{\ln(1+u)}$$

What does $u$ equal?

Comment: After some manipulations, solutions to this are solutions to the polynomial equation $(1+0.8u)^{1000}=(1+u)^{926}.$  The only obvious solution is $u=0,$ but this is not a solution to your equation.  Maybe I'm missing some non-obvious trick, but I don't think you can find an exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a method to approximate the value of *u* or WolframAlpha, you should get: 15.68427584

There doesn't seem to be a method to find an exact answer.